# How to use templates inside template class

Tags: c++, templates

If I want to make the following LRU cache class templated, how do I do it? I repeatedly get the following error:

```
Template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you 
forget 'typename'?"
```

Here's my code:

```
class LRU{
    int capacity;
public:
    std::list<std::pair<int, int>> doubly_queue;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator> elems;
    LRU(int c);
    int get(int key);
    void put(int key, int val);
};

LRU::LRU(int c){
   capacity = c;
}
```

How do I make the whole class templated?

This is the code after templating:

```
template<class T>
class LRU{
    int capacity;
public:
    std::list<std::pair<T, T>> doubly_queue;
    std::unordered_map<T, std::list<std::pair<T, T>>::iterator> elems;
    LRU(T c);
    int get(T key);
    void put(T key, T val);
};
```

Comment: What code do you have when you get the error? This is the non-templated code, so you should also add the templated code which gives you the error. What type are you trying to template, the key or value or both?

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename Type>
class LRU {
    Type capacity;
public:
    std::list<std::pair<Type, Type>> doubly_queue;
    std::unordered_map<Type, typename std::list<std::pair<Type, Type>>::iterator> elems;
    LRU(Type c);
    Type get(Type key);
    void put(Type key, Type val);
};

template <typename Type>
LRU<Type>::LRU(Type c){
   capacity = c;
}
```

The problem was about `std::list<std::pair<Type, Type>>::iterator` not being a type expected as a parameter of `std::unordered_map` template. It's resolved using `typename` keyword before it.
`typename` in this case is normally used when `::` is applied to templates.

Comment: This code doesnt work for me. It gives error "Template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?"

Comment: @user3285099, how about now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line:

```
std::unordered_map<Type, std::list<std::pair<Type, Type>>::iterator> elems;
```

With

```
std::unordered_map<Type, typename std::list<std::pair<Type, Type>>::iterator> elems;
```

This happens because you need to explicitly disambiguate member access syntax from nested types using `typename`